# How to Mock the security context in Spring MVC for testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

I need to test some protected urls, therefore I need to set up a mock security context in my tests (junit).
In particular I need perform some gets and post against my web application, using an authenticated user.
Below there is my code, I am able to create a such security context but I need to inject it in the 'MockMvc' object.
I set the authentication object in the security context and it works, the output result of 'SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()' is  chanelle.evans@616747.com but when I call the GET on /profile I have an assertion error because I am redirected to my login page, and not to /profile.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/security.xml", "classpath:spring/view.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles("default")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationTest {

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext ctx;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();

    //@formatter:off

    UserDetailsLogic userDetailsLogic = null;
    userDetailsLogic = ctx.getBean(UserDetailsLogic.class);
    final UserDetailsImp userDetailsImp = new UserDetailsImp();
    userDetailsImp.setAccountId(1001);
    userDetailsImp.setUserId(8001);
    userDetailsImp.setPassword("a378c92df7531df6fdf351f7ae1713f91f2dd2d45b9c6e1a8b02736ee3afec6595ff60465e9cb8da");
    userDetailsImp.setUsername("chanelle.evans@616747.com");
    userDetailsImp.setEmail("chanelle.evans@616747.com");

    final Collection<GrantedAuthorityImplementation> authorities= new ArrayList<GrantedAuthorityImplementation>();
    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImplementation("ROLE_USER"));

    userDetailsImp.setAuthorities(authorities);

    userDetailsImp.setAccountNonExpired(true);
    userDetailsImp.setAccountNonLocked(true);
    userDetailsImp.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
    userDetailsImp.setEnabled(true);

    final Authentication authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetailsImp.getUsername(), userDetailsImp.getPassword(), userDetailsImp.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

    System.out.println("principal:"+SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());      
    mockMvc.perform(get("/profile").principal(authToken)

            .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))

            .andDo(print())

            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl(null))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl(null));
    //@formatter:on     
}
```

I guess that I should put my authentication object inside the MockMvc object, but I do not know how 
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is something I wrote few days ago. I think that could be helpful (I tested the same thing against the login form, using the session for the second request) see loginUser1Ok(..))

See [MvcTest.java](https://github.com/m4nuv/easy-bank/blob/dev/src/test/java/com/manuv/test/controller/MvcTest.java) in

[m4nuv/easy-bank](https://github.com/m4nuv/easy-bank).

Comment: Hi Emanuele, thanks for your answer, I ended up exactly with the same solution.

Comment: The code sample you provided was extremely useful for me! Thank you!

Comment: It's nice the way you login to get a session, and then make your endpoint call. I was hoping to create a mock session without having to perform a login - then spoof the credentials.  The login is performed by a different service than the one I'm testing, so this won't work for me.

Comment: Hi, you should be able to create a mock session and fill it with everything you need and then set it the context when doing the request.

Answer (score 3):

Add in pom.xml

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-snaspho</id>
    <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

and use `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` for authorization request. [See the sample usage here](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog), and [Spring.io jira ticket SEC-2592](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2592).

Comment: Spring Security has improved test support in current version (4.0.1.RELEASE). Its documentation is available   Setting Up MockMvc and Spring Security(http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup) and using Mocked user  (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method)