# Junit authenticate SpringRest fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I'm facing an issue authenticating my app under junit-test.

I've got a CustomAuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
       //businness logic
       return auth;
    }
}
```

A SecurityConfig, that uses it

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          //some permission filters here
        }
    }
```

And my test, that is supposed to call on a Rest API and make sure, that answer is Ok.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class},locations = {"/dbContext.xml"})
@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")
@WebIntegrationTest
public class SimpleTest {
    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext);

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        Authentication user = customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "123"));
        context.setAuthentication(user);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
     }


    @Test
    public void makeSureLoginIsOk() {
        given().when().get("/myurl").then().statusCode(200);
    }
```

}

Well, the test always failes, because GET returns 401, instead of 200.
Can anyone help, what it wrong with SecurityContext?

Comment: @pvpkiran, Autowiring failes with exception No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext] found for dependency.

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user); doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer:
This post [How to Mock the security context in Spring MVC for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270973/how-to-mock-the-security-context-in-spring-mvc-for-testing) was helpfull

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext);
    RestAssuredMockMvc.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();
    Authentication user = customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "123"));
    RestAssuredMockMvc.authentication(user); //add this
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
}


@Test
public void makeSureLoginIsOk() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.get("/myurl").then().statusCode(200); //change given to RestAssured
}
```