# Change authorized user in tests

Tags: spring-security-test

I want to test access to a method for a group of users with different roles in one test. I am trying to change the logged in user like this:

```
@Test
void allMenusAuthorizePermissions() throws Exception {

        for (User user : ALL_ROLES_USERS) {
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            log.debug("User role: " + user.getAuthorities());

            if (user == ADMIN || user == EDITOR) {
                perform(get(MenuEditorController.MENU_EDITOR_URL).principal(authentication))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk());
            }else{
                perform(get(MenuEditorController.MENU_EDITOR_URL).principal(authentication))
                        .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
            }

        }
}
```

But no matter how hard I try, **perform(get (...))** is always performed from the first user from the **ALL_ROLES_USERS** array. This can be seen from the log:

```
o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e74255f0: Principal: +79990200001; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: CLIENT
```

-the same user in every iteration!

Any idea why this might be happening? Maybe **perform(get(...))** is passing the **JSESSIONID** of the first user? I don't know where to dig anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
@Test
    void allMenusAuthorizePermissions() throws Exception {

        for (User user : ALL_ROLES_USERS) {
            log.debug("User role: " + user.getAuthorities());

            if (user == ADMIN || user == EDITOR) {
//              perform(get(MenuEditorController.MENU_EDITOR_URL).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(user.getUsername()).authorities(user.getAuthorities())))
                perform(get(MenuEditorController.MENU_EDITOR_URL).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(user)))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk());
            }else{
                perform(get(MenuEditorController.MENU_EDITOR_URL).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(user)))
                        .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
            }

        }
    }
```

[How to Mock the security context in Spring MVC for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270973/how-to-mock-the-security-context-in-spring-mvc-for-testing)